# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, how to differentiate between external and iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

In the iOS simulator I've noticed the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification event comes through despite no actual keyboard popping up. I can toggle the keyboard with the command button + K key, but I have an issue with all of this.

Here is the code for setting up the event dispatcher:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

My issue is that the iOS keyboard does not actually pop up when this event comes in, and this is a problem for me because I have the following UIBarButtonItem which STILL does display when using the external keyboard on the PC, which I suspect is the default type of keyboard that it defaults to here. This is the code for the bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tap Here to Dismiss the Keyboard" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(keyboardDoneButtonClicked:)];
[doneButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, flexibleSpace, nil]];
[keyboardDoneButtonView setHidden:true];
self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
```

So, that being said, how can I differentiate between the external keyboard and iOS keyboard when UIKeyboardWillShowNotification comes through?

Comment: As a test, don't set the text view's `inputAccessoryView`. Now put focus on the text view using the external keyboard. Does the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` still happen?

Comment: @rmaddy It does not. So now the question is, is this a bug in Apple's dispatcher system or in the simulator, or the way I've set it up?

Comment: @rmaddy By the way, regarding our discussion before, I found I could dispatch to hide the `inputAccessoryView` via `[self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView setHidden:true];`. Now its just a matter of parsing the notification or finding some way to detect whether or not its in external keyboard or not. Do you happen to know of a reliable way to do so?

Comment: In the "WillShow" event, get the keyboard's height. If it's the same as the height of the `inputAccessoryView` then you know it's an external keyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy I was thinking the same thing, but `[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height` is `260` and `self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height` is only `44` when the external keyboard triggers the event with an added toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work reliably among the different iOS devices out there:

```
self.keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[self.keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tap Here to Dismiss the Keyboard" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarDoneButtonClicked:)];
[doneButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0], NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbar;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] fromView:self.view.window];
    if ((frame.origin.y + frame.size.height) > self.view.window.frame.size.height)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView setHidden:true];
        });
    else
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView setHidden:false];
        });
}

- (void)keyboardDidHideNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self.labelValueTextView.inputAccessoryView setHidden:false];
    });
}
```

There is one case that can occur in the simulator which as far as I know cannot occur in practice, and that is giving the user the ability to toggle between software keyboard and non-software keyboard in a specific situation, which is, the situation of being able to toggle off the software keyboard after its been toggled on. I think that when an external keyboard is plugged in while the software keyboard is on, it will go into a hybrid state until the user dismisses the software keyboard via the toolbar button in the above code, I think (but cannot test, as I do not have any external iOS compatible software keyboards). If someone could shed some more light on this, that would be greatly appreciated.